# XLPagerTabStrip: Title label doesn't show on pager tab

Tags: ios, swift3, pagertabstrip, xlpagertabstrip

I'd like to create pager tab like InstagramExample of XLPagerTabStrip and I follow all layout and coding to get the same. After adding everything I cannot see the title label on pager tab but I can swipe views as much as I add in array. Could anyone help me with this issue, please? I use the latest version of XLPagerTabStrip (v7.0.0).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your collection view is in front of title so you couldn't see it Run app by hiding collection view check titles visible or not.

Comment: @AvijitNagare, Although I hide the collection view, it's still same

Comment: Could you please share your code(My Account) and view controllers used in My Account(for swipe) of more understanding.

Comment: @AvijitNagare, Ok Sure. I added two images for coding in my question. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you set class "ButtonBarView" in "Identity Inspector" for "button bar  view" ?

Comment: @AvijitNagare Yes, I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pager tab is covered by NavigationBar.

so ,you can

1: to hide NavigationBar

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

2: to move tab

```
//get rod of containerView offset
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
//move tab    
buttonBarView.frame.origin.y = buttonBarView.frame.origin.y + 30
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: you were supposed to accept it as the answer to help searchers know that this was solved as well as to give points to the one solved it. @ZinMarHtet

Comment: Ok, @NaszNjokaSr.